# How to get userid by url wordpress in userpro plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'am using userPro plugin. My URL is below:

> http://www.example.com/profile/alex/

(alex is Username and I am in profile page I need to get alex in `function.php` file )

I set **Post name** in Permalink Settings from admin side

if I set it **Default** from Permalink Settings then I can get user id and url will made like this

> http://www.example.com/?page_id=522&up_username=alex

if i write `$_GET['up_username']` then i will get username. i want it with **Post name** in Permalink Settings.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Wordpress's in build function  `get_query_var()` to do this, as you are using Permalink based on POSTNAME you should replace :

```
$_GET['up_username'];
```

to

```
get_query_var('up_username');
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

This gets you the user object in Userpro:

```
$user = $userpro->get_member_by( get_query_var('up_username') );
print_r ($user);
echo '<br />';
echo ($user->user_login);
echo '<br />';
echo ($user->user_nicename);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a mix of the answer given by @sweet potato, but I included de function viewing_his_profile() when the logged user is in the profile page.

Really useful when you want to add some code outside the userpro's templates

Hope it helps

```
global $userpro;
if ($userpro->viewing_his_profile()) {
    debug(get_current_user_id());
} else {
    $user = $userpro->get_member_by(get_query_var('up_username'));
    debug($user->data->ID);
}
```